# Notify that user has arrived

Tags: android, google-maps

Currently i working on an Android based mobile application.
It will be integrated to an ERP system for users that needs travel a lot and want to calculate his travel time, etc to payoff.

I thing that it will be a good feature if my app can get a notify (let's say a Serice componenet) when the user is arrived to a location.
So let's say that user is using Google Maps' navigation system. I would like to notify that user is arrived so my app can do some administration work automatically.
I know how can i query my current location but don't know how can i notify about what user typed to the navigation system for his destination. I don't want to force him to type it to my program.

So is it possible to get some information in my app?

Thanks and sorry for my bad English!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to get the original navigation query from the Navigation application.

That is a custom application running on the device, and that app would have to make this info available to the rest of the system (which I doubt they allow).  I don't think the navigation app supplies the information that the user has arrived at their location either.

Bottom line, I don't think you can get information of any kind from the Google Navigation application, as they don't make this available.

Comment: Sadly i think that too :(  Just want to make that sure

Answer (score 0):

You can notify user using `Notification Manager` and you can do any background processing in `IntentService`.